How to solve Undefined Reference errors during cross-compilation from Visual Studio?
I have created a Solution File(.sln) from Microsoft Visual Studio and the my code (targeted for Unix based Systems) is using the standard Unix Libraries. My code seems to compile when I am simply compiling the code in my Linux Machine. But when I am using the Visual Studio .sln file, the code is giving me Undefined Reference errors.
: error : undefined reference to OPENSSL_init_ssl' : error : undefined reference to SSL_get_error'
: error : undefined reference to SSL_write' : error : undefined reference to SSL_shutdown'
What is the solution to this?
Please Note - I have installed the openssl libraries in my linux machine.
Trying to get the Solution File Compiled Successfully.
